# Can't solve how to get data from closed workbook and then paste only values

Tags: excel

I know my questions might seem simple, but really cant find the way.
The FSYS file is big, with macros, When I try simple test file instead of FSYS I can get file opened, and get data, but not values only.

It would be the best I could get data without opening the FSYS file.

Please help!

my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim src As Workbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\excel\FSYSv33.xlsx", True, True)


'Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\excel\FSYSv33.xlsx"

a = Workbooks("FSYSv33").Worksheets("Darbinis").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a



If Workbooks("FSYSv33").Worksheets("Darbinis").Cells(i, 4).Value = Workbooks("paimti").Worksheets("lapas1").Range("M1") Then
Workbooks("FSYSv33").Worksheets("Darbinis").Rows(i).Copy
Workbooks("paimti").Worksheets("lapas2").Activate
b = Worksheets("lapas2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("lapas2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Workbooks("paimti").Worksheets("lapas1").Activate
End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("lapas1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: *It would be the best I could get data without opening the FSYS file* Use that big file as a DataSource and then create a SQL query to it. Check http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/msquery-excel-relational-data.htm

Comment: Any options with code improvement? With MSQuery I'll work next because have to rebuild whole system.